# How to run custom scripts upon USB device plug-in?

Tags: usb, udev, uuid

What is the state-of-the-art method for automatically executing custom scripts upon USB device plug-in under current Linux distributions like Debian/CentOS/Fedora?

For example if you want to automatically mount/copy some files/umount a USB mass storage device based on its UUID (or device ID etc.).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Put a line like this in a file in `/etc/udev/rules.d`:

```
KERNEL=="sd*", ATTRS{vendor}=="Yoyodyne", ATTRS{model}=="XYZ42", ATTRS{serial}=="123465789", RUN+="/pathto/script"
```

Add a clause like `NAME="subdir/mydisk%n"` if you want to use a custom entry path under `/dev`.

Run `udevadm info -a -n sdb` to see what attributes you can match against (`attribute=="value"`; replace `sdb` by the device name automatically assigned to the disk, corresponding to the new entry created in `/dev` when you plug it in). Note that you can use `ATTRS` clauses from any *one* stanza: you can pick any stanza, but the `ATTRS` clauses must all come from the same stanza, you can't mix and match. You can mix `ATTRS` clauses with other types of clauses listed in a different stanza.

Comment: Is this answer still valid? Under no amount of fiddling can I get the script to execute (and touch a file). If you can provide the most basic example that executes a script when *anything* is plugged in, that would be great and we can work from there.

Comment: @Redsandro I have variations of this rule in my udev configuration and they're working. Did you plug the device out and back in, or run `udevadm trigger`? Does your system use udev? If you want to run a script when anything is plugged in, remove all the conditions (the clauses with `==`) (maybe the syntax requires one condition, I'm not sure; if it does, use `KERNEL=="*"`).

Comment: I tried that too, but since it works for you, I must be missing a step. I have [moved this question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15027461/how-to-execute-a-shellscript-when-i-plug-in-a-usb-device), so I can write example code.

Comment: Perhaps related, I think there is a time limit on how long the script may run. I believe it is very short (like 1 second or something). If it takes longer than that, then udev will kill it. You can work around this by using backgrounding the script with something like `at`. See "running external programs" on http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html

Comment: Just to add to this, for the sake of completeness, the file needs to have the suffix `.rules` and the files in the directory are read in a lexical order (convention uses numeric prefix to order them), and they can be beneath `/etc/`,  `/usr/lib` or `/run`. For more, [RTFM](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/udev.html).

Answer (score 19):

I looked in `/lib/udev/rules.d` for examples of disk related rules. On an Ubuntu system one rule file provides the environment variable `ID_FS_UUID_ENC` which you can use in own rule files.

Thus I put a custom rule file under `/etc/udev/rules.d/foodevice.rules`. Since it is not prefixed with a number, it is ran at last by udev. Btw, the udev daemon watches `/etc/udev/rules.d` for changes such that you don't need to restart it on file changes.

The content of `/etc/udev/rules.d/foodevice.rules` is:

```
ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="sd*[!0-9]", ENV{ID_FS_UUID_ENC}=="FFFF-AAAF",
  RUN+="/usr/bin/sudo -u juser /home/juser/path/script.sh"
```

(this is one rule - you  have to remove the newline after the ENV clause because udev does not have a line continuation mechanism)

A program started by udev blocks the daemon - thus it shouldn't run for a long time. I solved it via `at` - i.e. via detaching from the process doing the real work:

```
$ cat /home/juser/path/script.sh
#!/bin/sh
echo /path/to/mountcopystuff.sh | at now
```

Comment: You might need to reload the udev rules using `udevadm control --reload-rules`, depending on your distribution.

Comment: Instead of `at now` I suggest `batch`.

Comment: What to do when you have neither `at` nor `batch`? I'm in a embedded environment with [busybox](http://www.busybox.net/).

Comment: @natenho, you can use `~/path/mountcopystuff.sh &` - `at` etc. has the advantage that you get email notifications in case something goes wrong - but on an embedded system this probably isn't of much interest.

Comment: How to pass paramters to the script, for example, device name/path?

Comment: @Dims you can supply some of the [available substitutions](https://manpath.be/f37/7/udev#L414) as arguments to your script. Also, the script invoked by udev probably also has the (public) `ENV{}` keys available in its environment.