# Create serial console on plug in USB serial device

Tags: kernel, console, serial-port

I have a CentOS 7 headless system with no serial ports.  I *sometimes* want to access the server using a serial cable, so I plug in a USB serial cable (to my laptop's serial port) but I can't get a console/BASH from the connection.

Is there something I have to do to tell the kernel to always create a serial console on appearance of a USB serial port?

Comment: often headless systems have UART or JTAG pins for RS-232 which should be more sensible than using USB to serial.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT**: This won't work if you have a recent `udev` version, because `udev` prevents you from starting long-lived background processes in `RUN` scripts. You may or may not be able to get around this by prefixing the `getty` command with `setsid` but in any case it's discouraged if not outright disallowed. If you have a system which uses `systemd` then there is another way to achieve this, which I hope someone will supply with another answer. In the meantime, I'm leaving this answer here in case it works for you.

---

You cannot use a USB serial port as a console because USB is initialized too late in the boot sequence, long after the console needs to be working.

You can run `getty` on a USB serial port to allow you to log in and get a shell session on that port, but it will not be the system's console.

To get `getty` to start automatically, try this `udev` rule:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ENV{ID_BUS}=="usb", RUN+="/usr/local/sbin/usbrungetty"
```

Put that in a rules file in `/etc/udev/rules.d` and then create this executable script `/usr/local/sbin/usbrungetty`:

```
#!/bin/sh

/sbin/getty -L "$DEVNAME" 115200 vt102 &
```

Comment: With judicious use of `SYSTEMD_WANTS` you should be able to start `serial-getty@$name.service` directly, eliminate the shell script middleman entirely, and have proper full control over the resultant service.  This has the added bonus of conforming to the precept that udev children and grandchildren spawned from rules _not_ be long-running processes.

Comment: You're correct, there's a different "right way" to do this in the `systemd` world. I didn't include it because I don't know `systemd`. As for the long-running process restriction on `udev`-spawned scripts, my understanding is that it's okay if you start something in the background, as long as the actual script `udev` launches terminates quickly.

Comment: No. [As of 2012](http://blog.fraggod.net/2012/06/16/proper-ish-way-to-start-long-running-systemd-service-on-udev-event-device-hotplug.html), [grandchildren must be short-lived](http://jasonwryan.com/blog/2014/01/20/udev/), [too](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56243/), [now](http://askubuntu.com/questions/290795/).  Another benefit of not having a hand-written `getty` invocation is that `serial-getty@.service` is [well known](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/serial-console.html) as the place to tweak settings [such as TERM](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/198949/5132).

Comment: I stand corrected.

Comment: Now if only [jasonwryan](http://stackexchange.com/users/366830/) of aforelinked web log had a StackExchange account and there were some form of @jasonwryan txt spk for getting xyr attention so that xe knew that there was an answer that xe could write.  (-:

Comment: @JdeBP - it actually doesn't unless he's in the thread.

Comment: Since CentOS7 uses systemd, can someone provide an example of how to do this?