# Run service after ttyUSB0 becomes available

Tags: systemd, ttyusb

I made a systemd service that launches a simple .sh to read data from a serial connection. If I run the service manually after booting it works fine, but when I try to run it automatically at boot it fails because the .sh can't yet read from ttyUSB0 (`awk: fatal: cannot open file /dev/ttyUSB0' for reading (No such file or directory`).

Is there any way to make the service wait for ttyUSB0 and then run the .sh? I tried something like after=ttyUSB0 but that doesn't work.

```
[Unit] 
Description=Serial logger

[Service] 
ExecStart=/serial_script.sh

[Install] 
WantedBy=default.target
```

Answer (score 12):

<s>Consider using an `udev` rule instead of a `systemd` service to start your script.</s> Never mind, since starting long-running processes from udev is not recommended, and newer udev versions may actively try and prevent it by having a strict time limit for udev transactions and processes spawned by them.

But if you need to do it in udev (e.g. in an old system that has an old version of `systemd`), something like this in `/etc/udev/rules.d/99-serial-logger.rules` should work:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="ttyUSB0", RUN+="/serial_script.sh"
```

---

When implementing this as a systemd service (the current recommended way), remove the `WantedBy=default.target` line from your service and make your `udev` rule like this:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", KERNEL=="ttyUSB0", TAG+="systemd", ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}+="your-serial-logger.service"
```

As a result, `udev` should tell `systemd` to start your service when the device appears, and to stop it if/when the device is removed.

Comment: The systemd route is probably better, since starting long-running processes from udev is not recommended. See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/249630/233460

Answer (score 0):

Rules like this in UDEV dont work

```
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="ttyUSB0", RUN+="/serial_script.sh"
```

Use `serial_script.sh | at now` to run the job detached from udev process. UDEV prevents you from starting long-lived background processes in RUN or PROGRAM scripts.
But, the "right way" to do this is with systemd. I recommend reading [Instantiated Services with systemd](https://0pointer.de/blog/projects/instances.html) and [Proper way to start long-running systemd service on udev event](https://blog.fraggod.net/2012/06/16/proper-ish-way-to-start-long-running-systemd-service-on-udev-event-device-hotplug.html) and [Starting systemd service instance for device from udev](https://blog.fraggod.net/2015/01/12/starting-systemd-service-instance-for-device-from-udev.html)