# How to wait for the copying process (cp) to finish?

Tags: shell-script, process, raspberry-pi, cp

I want my RPi 2 (with `MiniBian` (a minimal version of Debian-based `Raspbian` OS) as its OS) to execute a script when it detects a USB flash memory is inserted. So this is what I have done:

I created `/etc/udev/rules.d/10-usbstick.rules` with these contents:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="block", KERNEL=="sd*" SYMLINK+="usbflash", RUN+="/path/to/myscript.sh"
```

And then created `/path/to/myscript.sh` with these contents:

```
#!/bin/bash

mount /dev/usbflash /mnt/

service omxd stop

rm -r /path/to/myfolder/*
cp -f /mnt/*.mp4 /path/to/myfolder/
cp -f /mnt/*.avi /path/to/myfolder/

sleep 1
umount /dev/usbflash

halt
```

Now, when I insert a USB flash memory, it recognizes it, mounts it, stops the `omxd` daemon and removes all the older files.

But the problems is that it shuts down (`halt`) before all the files have been copied. I check later and see that only 1 file has been copied, and it has not been copied correctly, like the `halt` command has been executed at the middle of the copying procedure.

So, I decided to use `wait` command to ensure that the `halt` command be executed only at the end. I edited the `/path/to/myscript.sh` file as this:

```
#!/bin/bash

mount /dev/usbflash /mnt/

PID1 = $!
wait PID1

service omxd stop

rm -r /path/to/myfolder/*

PID2 = $!
wait PID2

cp -f /mnt/*.mp4 /path/to/myfolder/

PID3 = $!
wait PID3

cp -f /mnt/*.avi /path/to/myfolder/

PID4 = $!
wait PID4

sleep 1
umount /dev/usbflash

PID5 = $!
wait PID5

halt
```

But again the same scenario happens: the system halts at the middle of the copying procedure.

So what's wrong with my system?

What shall I do to tell the system to `halt` ***only after*** all the new files have been successfully copied !?

---

***Update 1***

Adding `sync` before `umount` and `halt` didn't work. The same scenario happens again.

***Update 2***

I edited the `/path/to/myscript.sh` file as the following:

```
mkdir -p /mnt/usb
if mount /dev/usbflash /mnt/usb
then
    service omxd stop
    rm -r /path/to/myfolder/*
    cp -f /mnt/usb/*.mp4 /path/to/myfolder/
    cp -f /mnt/usb/*.avi /path/to/myfolder/
    sync
    umount /mnt/usb
    sync
    shutdown -h now
fi
```

But it didn't help either! The same scenario happens again! And this time it was worse: it didn't copy any file at all!

***Update 3***

I changed the `/etc/udev/rules.d/10-usbstick.rules` to the following:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="block", KERNEL=="sd[a-z]1" SYMLINK+="usbflash", RUN+="/path/to/myscript.sh"
```

Now it works great. It copies all the files. But there's a new problem: It doesn't shut down!

***Update 4***

I found something new:

When I run `myscript.sh` directly from the terminal, it works perfect: removes the older files, copies the new files, and shuts down the system. Perfect.

So, why doesn't it execute `myscript.sh` perfectly when I call it from udev rules?

And is there any other way to shut down the system after it has copied the files !?

Comment: the first thing that comes to mind is that the kernel hasn't finished flushing the files to disk, but I would have assumed a umount would do it. does adding a 'sync' before the umount help?

Comment: Dear @JeffSchaller , adding `sync` before `umount` didn't help. The same scenario happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why changing the kernel name would have made a difference (perhaps `sd*1` runs after `sd*` allowing a bit more time for work to get done?), but udev doesn't like long-running actions in events:

> Starting daemons or other long running processes is not appropriate for
>   udev; the forked processes, detached or not, will be unconditionally killed
>   after the event handling has finished.

#### Original `nohup` suggestion

I originally suggested `nohup` before fully reading my own links :) -- which suggest that this may not actually work

udev rule:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="block", KERNEL=="sd[a-z]1" SYMLINK+="usbflash", RUN+="/path/to/mywrapper.sh"
```

`mywrapper.sh` (Note: if you don't redirect the output nohup may litter your directory with a `nohup.out` file):

```
#!/bin/sh
nohup /path/to/myscript.sh >/log/myscript.log 2>&1 &
```

Then `myscript.sh` can be what it is.

#### Newer `systemd` suggestion

The third link below suggests firing off a systemd service when the device is plugged in. That blog entry does more work than I think you need due to ensuring that the device information is passed to the service, I *think* you can get away with simply using systemd as your method of daemonization:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="block", KERNEL=="sd[a-z]1" SYMLINK+="usbflash", RUN+="/usr/bin/systemctl start my-usb-backup.service"
```

With a simple oneshot service `my-usb-backup.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=run myscript
[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/path/to/myscript.sh
```

See also:

- [How to run long time process on Udev event?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56243/how-to-run-long-time-process-on-udev-event)
- [What is the easiest way to “detach/daemonize” a Bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4369866/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-detach-daemonize-a-bash-script)
- [Proper(-ish) way to start long-running systemd service on udev event (device hotplug)](http://blog.fraggod.net/2012/06/16/proper-ish-way-to-start-long-running-systemd-service-on-udev-event-device-hotplug.html)
- [More than you wanted to know about systemd](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/systemd)

Comment: Good catch on the `udev` warning about killing processes. I'd missed that entirely. +1

Comment: Thank you @DeanSerenevy for your helpful answer. This is exactly the main problem, as I noted in update 4. I'll try both `nohup` and `systemd`, and see what happens.

Comment: One question @DeanSerenevy : How shall I create and edit a service ?

Comment: And where should I save this `my-usb-backup.service` file after creation @DeanSerenevy?

Comment: @DeanSerenevy , One problem: There's no `systemctl` in `/usr/bin`. And there's no `systemd` in `/etc/` . What shall I do ?

Comment: Thanks @DeanSerenevy for your help. The `nohup` method solved the problem.

Answer (score 6):

There is no point in a `wait` for a command unless it's run in the background (which yours aren't). What you may be missing is a `sync` to force all writes to the media, although that should happen as part of the `umount` command.

I'd be interested to see if this simplified script works as you want:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin

mkdir -p /mnt/usb
if mount /dev/usbflash /mnt/usb
then
    service omxd stop
    rm -r /path/to/myfolder/*
    cp -f /mnt/usb/*.mp4 /path/to/myfolder/
    cp -f /mnt/usb/*.avi /path/to/myfolder/
    sync
    umount /mnt/usb
    sync
    shutdown -h now
fi
```

I must admit I'm a little puzzled, as your description seems to suggest you want to update files on the USB stick. But your code updates files in `/path/to/my/folder` *from* the USB stick rather than writing to `/mnt/usb/...`

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34403/discussion-on-answer-by-roaima-how-to-wait-for-the-copying-process-cp-to-finis).