# Linux script to automate transferring data into CAN messages for CANblue V2 from IXAAT

Tags: bash, shell-script

We have some data files with messages for a microcontroller.

We use Blue CAN v2 [IXXAT](https://www.ixxat.com/products/products-industrial/can-interfaces/usb-can-interfaces/usb-to-can-v2-professional?ordercode=1.01.0281.12001) with a simulator to transfer messages to the microcontroller.

Currently we are using the GUI, but can we use some module in linux to write a script to automate it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Udev rule setting up SocketCAN socket only works correctly only when run manually](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/285858/udev-rule-setting-up-socketcan-socket-only-works-correctly-only-when-run-manuall)

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to send/receive data on the CAN interface,**
you should install `can-utils`:

```
sudo apt install can-utils
```

The repository for can-utils can be found at
https://github.com/linux-can/can-utils.

---

**To send data to the CAN bus,**
use the `cansend` utility:

```
cansend can0 123#1122334455667788
```

The above command will send a CAN message on `can0` with the identifier `0x123` and the data bytes `[ 0x11, 0x22, 0x33, 0x44, 0x55, 0x66, 0x77, 0x88 ]`. Values are always treated as hexadecimal.

---

**To display a list of received messages on the bus**
in realtime, use the `candump` utility:

```
candump can0
```

---

Source: [Send/Receive Data On SocketCAN](https://blog.mbedded.ninja/programming/operating-systems/linux/how-to-use-socketcan-with-the-command-line-in-linux)