# udev rule to trigger systemd service

Tags: systemd, udev

I am modifying my working udev rule (`/etc/udev/rules.d/10-local.rules`):

```
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1366", ATTRS{idProduct}=="1015", ATTRS{serial}=="000621000000", SYMLINK+="ttymkw"
```

to this (end of row):

```
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1366", ATTRS{idProduct}=="1015", ATTRS{serial}=="000621000000", SYMLINK+="ttymkw", TAG+="systemd", SYSTEMD_WANTS="offnet-uart-log.service"
```

I have user service `offnet-uart-log.service` in `~/.config/systemd/user`, which I can manually trigger, but I don't get this far yet.

With the added `, TAG+="systemd", SYSTEMD_WANTS="offnet-uart-log.service"` at the end of my udev rule, the symlink is not created (I reload with `sudo udevadm control --reload-rules && sudo udevadm trigger`).

This tells me that the rule is wrong, but I don't know why. Could be related to udev being owned by root, while the service is owned by the user? Did I misunderstand `WANTS`?

I've tried all four combinations of `SYSTEM_USER_WANTS` or `SYSTEM_WANTS`, and `=` or `+=`. Removing the `*_WANTS` makes the symlink appear, so the error is in the `*_WANTS`.

How do I make my tty device trigger the log service?

---

EDIT: as mentioned in my own answer below, modifying `SYSTEM_USER_WANTS` to `ENV{SYSTEM_USER_WANTS}` works. Why is it required?

Answer (score 1):

[This blog post](http://blog.fraggod.net/2012/06/16/proper-ish-way-to-start-long-running-systemd-service-on-udev-event-device-hotplug.html) does what I want, and thanks to it I replaced `SYSTEMD_USER_WANTS` with `ENV{SYSTEMD_USER_WANTS}`, which made it work.

I still don't understand why the `ENV{}` construct is needed, and why I haven't found it in the docs.

Comment: If you look at [man 7 udev](https://linux.die.net/man/7/udev), you'll see that `SYSTEMD_USER_WANTS` isn't valid in a udev rule, while `ENV` sets a device property value (and systemd uses this property value for its purposes).

Answer (score 0):

If you really just want to *trigger* a service, you would add

```
RUN{program}="/bin/systemctl --user start offnet-uart-log.service"
```

to your *udev* rule. This would require that your service is of type `oneshot` or `exec`, so that the call to `systemd` returns within the usual short timeframe allowed by `udev` (see e.g. discussions here [How to run long time process on Udev event?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56243/how-to-run-long-time-process-on-udev-event) and on other pages discussing `udev` and automatic mounts.

Comment: Thanks. I read this http://blog.fraggod.net/2012/06/16/proper-ish-way-to-start-long-running-systemd-service-on-udev-event-device-hotplug.html , which is doing what I'm trying. They advice against using `systemctl start` at the bottom, which I tend to agree with.

Comment: I agree, that looks like the more proper way to do it (although the approach I suggested worked for me so far).

Comment: I suggest tacking on --no-block.  Udev does NOT like latency.  And running systemctl has it's uses if you need something to run every time guaranteed, like display mirroring.