# Run display dependent command in a system setting event

Tags: systemd, udev, xauth

I am working on a systemd/udev setting that I would like to share upstream, however I can't get it to work in a non-hacky way. Essentially, I have this script as the exec of a systemd service:

```bash
      ICON="somepath/dslr-camera-white.png"

      function on-display() {
          local sdisplay=$(echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE)
          if [ "$sdisplay" == "wayland" ]; then
          local display=":$(echo $WAYLAND_DISPLAY)"
          else
          local display=":$(ls /tmp/.X11-unix/* | sed 's#/tmp/.X11-unix/X##' | head -n 1)"
          fi
          
          local user=$(who | grep '('$display')' | awk '{print $1}' | head -n 1)

          local uid=$(id -u $user)

          sudo -u $user DISPLAY=$display DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/$uid/bus "$@"
      }

      cleanup() {
          on-display notify-send -i $ICON "Disconnected" "The DSLR Camera has been turned off." --app-name="DSLR Webcam"
          trap - SIGTERM && kill -- -$$
      }

      trap cleanup SIGINT SIGTERM EXIT

      on-display notify-send -i $ICON "Connected" "The DSLR Camera has been turned on and it is ready to use." --app-name="DSLR Webcam"
      on-display yad --window-icon=$ICON --image=$ICON --no-buttons --title="DSLR Webcam" --notification --listen &

      output=$(v4l2-ctl --list-devices)
      line=$(echo "$output" | grep "Virtual Camera")
      vdevice=$(echo "$output" | sed -n "/$line/{n;s/^\t\+//p;}")
      gphoto2 --stdout --capture-movie | ffmpeg -i - -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p -threads 0 -f v4l2 $vdevice
```

The point of the service is to be started by an udev rule when an specific gphoto2 supported camera is plugged in, therefor I have these udev rules:

```bash
ACTION=="add", ATTR{idVendor}=="04a9", ATTR{idProduct}=="3218", RUN+="systemctl start dslr-webcam.service"
ACTION=="remove", ATTR{idVendor}=="04a9", ATTR{idProduct}=="3218", RUN+="systemctl stop dslr-webcam.service"
```

So far so "ok", because I have read on alternatives to using `RUN` for a systemd service, but regardless... The issue here is specifically the call to `yad`.

`yad` is a program that allows you to display dialogue boxes from the CLI, I am leveraging it for its ability to make a systrey icon, as I would like for one to show up when the camera is active.

### The problem

Unlike `notify-send`, which probably works off some common socket, `yad` requires the appropriate `XAUTHORITY` set in order for it to work, otherwise you will get `cannot open display: :0`. The hacky solution in my case is to simply set it the right Xauthority, since I am using SDDM (display manager), it resides in the `/tmp` directory, so I can add this to the script:

```bash
XAUTHORITY=$(ls /tmp/xauth*)
```

And then it works... But this is terrible, it makes a lot of assumptions, in fact the whole `on-display` function also seems like a bad idea. If I took this to a different system, it probably wouldn't work, because the proper Xauthority could be in a myriad of places, and I haven't even tried Wayland yet (I will leave that for later).

### What about `xauth`

I thought I could somehow use `xauth` to retrieve the right Xauthority, but that doesn't seem to be the case... This script is a system service, so my `xauth info` returns `Authority file: /root/.xauthWV7OfU`, and running it as the right user `sudo -u $user xauth info` gives me `Authority file: /home/myuser/.Xauthority`, none of which work when given to `yad`. The correct `XAUTHORITY` is set by the display manager, so I think I could only get it from child processes of it.

I have also tried all the approaches give by this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/429106/528934), but the first one would not work, as `XAUTHORITY` isn't actually in the system env, and the second one (aside from the mentioned pitfalls), doesn't work, it says the xauth file is at `/run/sddm/xauth_KvyuHd`, but trying to use it doesn't work, so it is not the same xauth file as `/tmp/xauth_FzoQqz`

From the same question as the previous one, [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/429162/528934) approach seems to work, but I don't know how portable it is. And still seems hacky.

---

### Run as user service

Perhaps this is the most promising one, as nothing in that script prevents it from being run as a user (it also gets rid of `on-display`), I did try this approach, and while if the camera was plugged-in and I ran `systemctl --user start dslr-webcam.service` it would work as expected (including `yad`), now I have a problem with the `udev` rule. I searched many places, including [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/550279/udev-rule-to-trigger-systemd-service), but I cannot find how to run a systemd user service from an `udev` rule, and to me that doesn't really make any sense either, how would `udev` know what user to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't directly run user services from udev rules; instead, you should *have udev tell systemd that the device wants a particular user service* to run.

With a `TAG+="systemd", ENV{SYSTEMD_USER_WANTS}="dslr-webcam.service"` like this:

```
ACTION=="add", ATTR{idVendor}=="04a9", ATTR{idProduct}=="3218". TAG+="systemd", ENV{SYSTEMD_USER_WANTS}="dslr-webcam.service"
ACTION=="remove", ATTR{idVendor}=="04a9", ATTR{idProduct}=="3218", TAG+="systemd", ENV{SYSTEMD_USER_WANTS}="dslr-webcam.service"
```

Since your `dslr-webcam.service` requires GUI access, it should declare itself as `BindsTo=graphical-session.target` and `After=graphical-session.target`. When declared this way, the service should get the right DISPLAY and XAUTHORITY variables automatically.

By the way, thanks for sharing your idea; it gave me inspiration to set up something very similar...

Comment: Oh so that is what I had to do! I was running around in circles for ages for this one. Just one follow-up question, how does `systemd` know that the second call from `udev` is to stop the service? The two rules are identical, expect for the action that triggers them.

Comment: The `add` event causes systemd to *create* a `*.device` unit with a "Wants" dependency on the user service unit, the `remove` event causes that device unit to go away, and then the service unit will no longer be wanted by anything. If you need to make the stop behavior stronger, you might add something like `Requisite=<dslr>.device` to the `dslr-webcam.service`, assuming that the DSLR's `*.device` unit gets a stable name. If the name is awkward, add `ENV{SYSTEMD_ALIAS}="/sys/subsystem/usb/dslr"` or similar to the udev rules to get a device unit with a more useful name.