# How to execute a shellscript when I plug-in a USB-device

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, udev

I want to execute a script when I plug in a device in my Linux machine. For example, run `xinput` on mouse or a backupscript on a certain drive.

I have seen a lot of articles on this, most recently [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28548/how-to-run-custom-scripts-upon-usb-device-plug-in) and [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsbDriveDoSomethingHowto). But I just can't get it to work.

Here's some simple examples trying to get at least some kind of response.

**/etc/udev/rules.d/test.rules**

```
#KERNEL=="sd*", ATTRS{vendor}=="*", ATTRS{model}=="*", ATTRS{serial}=="*", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/test.sh"
#KERNEL=="sd*", ACTION=="add", "SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{model}=="My Book 1140    ", ATTRS{serial}=="0841752394756103457194857249", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/test.sh"
#ACTION=="add", "SUBSYSTEM=="usb", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/test.sh"
#KERNEL=="sd*", ACTION=={add}, RUN+="/usr/local/bin/test.sh"
KERNEL=="sd*", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/test.sh"
KERNEL=="*", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/test.sh"
```

**/usr/local/bin/test.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo touched >> /var/log/test.log

if [ "${ACTION}" = "add" ] && [ -f "${DEVICE}" ]
then
    echo ${DEVICE} >> /var/log/test.log
fi
```

The rules folder is watched by `inotify` and should be active immediately. I keep replugging my keyboard, mouse, tablet, memorystick and usb-drive, but nothing. No log file touched.

Now, what would be the most simple way to at least know something is working? It's easier to work from something that's working than from something that's not.

Comment: Didn't you mean to post on [unix.se]? What's your kernel version? Did you run `udevadm trigger` or plug a device in to apply the new rule?

Comment: Yes, I do that after every edit of the rules to try them out. I edited the question accordingly. This is the way udev works for a while now, but I am running `3.5.0-23-generic`.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

If you want to run the script on a specific device, you can use the vendor and product ids

- In  `/etc/udev/rules.d/test.rules`:

  ```
  ATTRS{idVendor}=="152d", ATTRS{idProduct}=="2329", RUN+="/tmp/test.sh"
  ```
- in `test.sh`:

  ```
  #! /bin/sh

  env >>/tmp/test.log
  file "/sys${DEVPATH}" >>/tmp/test.log

  if [ "${ACTION}" = add -a -d "/sys${DEVPATH}" ]; then
  echo "add ${DEVPATH}" >>/tmp/test.log
  fi
  ```

With `env`, you can see what environment is set from udev and with `file`, you will discover the file type.

The concrete attributes for your device can be discovered with `lsusb`

```
lsusb
```

gives

> ...
>   Bus 001 Device 016: ID 152d:2329 JMicron Technology Corp. / JMicron USA Technology Corp. JM20329 SATA Bridge
>   ...

Comment: This is interesting! It seems that it has no permission to write to /log/. It _does_ write to /tmp/. I guess it had no permission to read my previous testscripts either.

Comment: @Redsandro This was not intentional, just for, well, testing purposes. Anyway, I'm glad it helped. ;-)

Comment: I would like to encourage you to also check out [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/582723/can-udev-somehow-trigger-zenity-for-a-logged-in-user-in-a-session) and see if your knowledge can be valuable there. :)

Comment: You can also add `ACTION=="add",` directly to the rule definition.

Comment: Huh. So `lsusb` provides `idVendor:idProduct` in its output (per example rules file), but that same information is referred to as `ID_VENDOR_ID` and `ID_MODEL_ID` in the output of `udevadm info --query=all /device/path`. The naming inconsistency is confusing. Are model and product considered different info?

Comment: @sherrellbc I don't know. But consider, that `lsusb` is specific to USB, while `udevadm` is more general and covers a wider range of device types.

Answer (score 11):

This isn't directly about your question but about what you're doing. If you start a backup script from udev you will face two main issues :

1. Your script might be started before the device is ready and can be mounted, you have to keep the KERNEL=="sd*" condition if you want to use the /dev node to mount it
2. More important, if your script takes some time to execute (which can easily be the case with a backup script) it will be killed shortly after it is started (about 5s)
3. You will face many complicated user permission issues

My advice is to create a script in your user home which listens to a named pipe and which will be started asynchronously like :

```
#!/bin/bash

PIPE="/tmp/IomegaUsbPipe"
REMOTE_PATH="/path/to/mount/point"
LOCAL_PATH="/local/path/"


doSynchronization()
{
  #your backup here
}

trap "rm -f $PIPE" EXIT

#If the pipe doesn't exist, create it
if [[ ! -p $PIPE ]]; then
    mkfifo $PIPE
fi

#If the disk is already plugged on startup, do a syn
if [[ -e "$REMOTE_PATH" ]]
then
    doSynchronization
fi

#Make the permanent loop to watch the usb connection
while true
do
    if read line <$PIPE; then
        #Test the message read from the fifo
        if [[ "$line" == "connected" ]]
        then
            #The usb has been plugged, wait for disk to be mounted by KDE
            while [[ ! -e "$REMOTE_PATH" ]]
            do
                sleep 1
            done
            doSynchronization
        else
            echo "Unhandled message from fifo : [$line]"
        fi
    fi
done
echo "Reader exiting"
```

Note : I use auto-mount with kde so I check for the folder to appear. You can pass the /dev/sd* parameter in the fifo from the udev rule and mount it yourself in the script. To write to the fifo don't forget that udev is not a shell and that redirection doesn't work. Your RUN should be like :

RUN+="/bin/sh -c '/bin/echo connected >> /tmp/IomegaUsbPipe'"

Comment: Great use of named pipes here. I was wondering you could also just create an arbitrary file in tmp and look for it as well instead of a named pipe, correct?

Comment: @jamescampbell The pipe allows you to do a `read` which blocks until something is written to the pipe. You use 0 CPU cycles during that `read` which is way better than checking for the existance of a file which would require a sleep (i.e. a polling solution) and the detection could happen seconds later if you use a long sleep.

Comment: @AlexisWilke thank you that is super useful to know why that pipe is better

Comment: With disks automounting, code like `while [[ ! -e "$REMOTE_PATH" ]]; do sleep 1` seems to use 0 CPU as well. Since just waiting for the path works. are there still good reasons to use a pipe?

Comment: @AlF How is that zerp cycles? "If REMOTE_PATH does not exist execute command sleep 1. and then try again" that is a loop with a relatively expensive check for existing file. If sleep isn't internal to shell, it will even start a new process.

Answer (score 6):

I've posted a solution on https://askubuntu.com/a/516336 and I'm also copy-pasting the solution over here.

I wrote a Python script using [pyudev](http://pyudev.readthedocs.org/) that I leave running in the background. That script listens to udev events (thus, it's very efficient) and runs whatever code I want. In my case, [it runs `xinput` commands to setup my devices](https://github.com/denilsonsa/small_scripts/blob/75d0387/auto_configure_upon_usb_device_change.py) ([link to the most recent version](https://github.com/denilsonsa/small_scripts/blob/master/auto_configure_upon_usb_device_change.py)).

Here's a short version of the same script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import pyudev
import subprocess

def main():
    context = pyudev.Context()
    monitor = pyudev.Monitor.from_netlink(context)
    monitor.filter_by(subsystem='usb')
    monitor.start()

    for device in iter(monitor.poll, None):
        # I can add more logic here, to run different scripts for different devices.
        subprocess.call(['/home/foo/foobar.sh', '--foo', '--bar'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: thanks to your answer I was able to create solution that detects when I connect my USB keyboard and it changes the layout automatically - https://askubuntu.com/a/1414424/94200

Answer (score -1):

To run the script on the boot when usb device is inserted I use solution below:

Format the pendrive or any other usb storage and give it a name when doing so. Then 
in `/etc/rc.local` 
add line `ls -q /dev/disk/by-label > /home/pi/label.txt`

it will create a txt file called label.txt ( can be any other name )

then again in /etc/rc.local add another 2 lines:

```
if  grep -q USB_drive_name /home/pi/label.txt; then
sudo /home/pi/script.sh
```

Now everytime pendrive with name USB_drive_name is inserted it will run the script.

With a few little modifications above solution can be used when system is up and running.

Comment: Does not answer the question: This only covers boot-time (and using `udev` for other times are not a "few little modifications") and the Raspberry Pi. There is an unnecessary `sudo` - `rc.local` runs as root, it is a privilege escalation issue - a file that is editable by a normal user is run as root.