# Trying to get sh to run when usb camera is connected

Tags: shell, usb, camera

I have tried this: [How to execute a shellscript when I plug-in a USB-device](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65891/how-to-execute-a-shellscript-when-i-plug-in-a-usb-device) and have the following output for "lsusb":

```
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 046d:0825 Logitech, Inc. Webcam C270
```

and in /etc/udev/rules.d/camset.rules

```
ATTRS{idvendor}=="046d", ATTRS{idproduct}=="0825", RUN+="camset.sh"
```

and camset.sh is located at the root directory.  When I run "sh camset.sh" it runs fine so I don't think there is any problem with that.  Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

From the [udev documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/kernel/hotplug/udev/udev.html):

> RUN
>   (…)
>   If no absolute path is given, the program is expected to live in `/usr/lib/udev`, otherwise the absolute path must be specified.

Udev doesn't use the `PATH` environment variable. You need to specify a full path. According to the usual directory structure conventions, this should be `/usr/local/sbin/camset.sh` — `/usr/local` for locally-written files, `sbin` for a directory containing executables that only make sense for root. Don't put files in the root directory.