# How to write shell script to execute rsync each time I plug in my external ssd?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, rsync, udev

I want to execute rsync command which syncs my local directory with the external ssd. I followed the instructions given in [this link.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65891/how-to-execute-a-shellscript-when-i-plug-in-a-usb-device) to execute some command based on udev rules. This shows how to run the command for specific usb drive based on idVendor and idProduct. Here is the command I have in my `/etc/udev/rules.d/test.rules:`

```
ATTRS{idVendor}=="0781", ATTRS{idProduct}=="558c", RUN+="/temp/auto_back.sh"
```

and in `/tmp/auto_back.sh` I just have

```
#!/bin/bash

# auto backup command 

rsync -avzh /home/abhishek/Dropbox /media/abhishek/Hachiko
```

I don't have much insight about this. I just thought it might work. But it doesn't. I read that sometimes the command gets executed before the drive is even mounted. Can you give me some insight on what I am doing wrong, and how this thing works? Also, is there any way to make the command in script to wait for some time before it executes?

Answer (score 1):

Udev will work only if you pass correct information like below for usb,

```
KERNEL=="sd*", ATTRS{vendor}=="<Vendor name>", ATTRS{model}=="<Model>", ATTRS{serial}=="<serial>", RUN+="/your script path"
```

Alternatively,

I could not write complete code since not sure kind of hardware and other details, however check this logic and put in **crontab** either use long running process or keep on checking your logs. New hardware should be visible in dmesg output.

```
if "string matching in dmesg" && "within 30s"; then 
     check disk is properly mounted
     check disk is writable
     start backup
fi
```

Put check logic for disk is writable and properly mounted before starting backup.

Comment: Thanks. I will try **crontab**. But can you check that the idea I am trying is valid or not?

Answer (score 0):

you could add a wait for the disk to mount

eg:

```
while ! [ -w /media/abhishek/Hachiko ]
do sleep 1
done
```

but that requires that you are logged into the GUI when you plug the drive in it's probably better to over-ride the automount and mount the drive explicitly.

Comment: What do you mean by 'logged into the GUI'? I'm using mint 19. That means I am using GUI, right?

Comment: you are after you log in.