# Escalate permissions through a background shell script

Tags: shell, permissions, printer

I would like to write to a Device File (of a printer) located at `/dev/usb/lp0`. The file is owned by `lp` user and group. This file is created whenever I connect my printer device to the system.

I tried adding myself to the `lp` group. However the `lp0` file doesn't appear when the printer is connected. Removing myself from the group fixes the issue.

---

One solution to get write permission is to -

1. Detect whenever the device is connected
2. Trigger a shell script that runs `sudo chmod 0666 /dev/usb/lp0`

This led me to the answer at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/28711

---

The shell script is successfully triggered but it doesn't run the `sudo command`*, since the shell script was not executed from the terminal. I have tried using `sudo` and `gksudo`, both have failed to prompt me to enter password i.e, I am ***unable to escalate permissions through a background shell script***.

### What I have tried?

1. `setuid` from [Unix & Linux @ StackExchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364/allow-setuid-on-shell-scripts), but it seems to be a very bad idea.
2. `echo 'my_insecure_password' | sudo -S command`, it didn't work*.

I did not try `Polkit`, which was suggested in other answers, due to the level of its complexity. But I am willing to go for it with proper directions.

Comment: Can you explain, better, the 2nd paragraph. My interpretation is that `/dev/usb/lp0` is added when the printer is plugged in, but not if you are in group `lp`. Is this correct understanding? As it seems odd.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. It does seem odd. Maybe I should try it once again.

Comment: @steeldriver Please elaborate and post your comment (from askubuntu) as an answer here.

Comment: AFAIK udev rules will be run as root - you shouldn't need sudo in your script. However, you shouldn't need a script at all: you can write a rule that sets the MODE directly - see the example [Controlling permissions and ownership](http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html#ownership) from this [Writing udev rules](http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html) tutorial

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding yourself to the `lp` group is probably the best solution here. That would *not* cause the `lp0` file not to appear. (It's theoretically possible that your system has been configured to cause `lp0` not to appear if you're in the `lp` group, but 1. that would have to be a local configuration, not a default setup from a distribution; and 2. I don't see why someone would have set this up.)

---

What follows is for academic interest only. In your scenario, you don't need this.

If you needed to change the permissions on the device file, then [How to run custom scripts upon USB device plug-in?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28548/how-to-run-custom-scripts-upon-usb-device-plug-in) is not exactly what you need — that's for more complex cases that require a script. To change the Unix permissions or the ownership on a device file, use `OWNER`, `GROUP` and `MODE` assignments directly in the udev rule. That is, do create a file under `/etc/udev/rules.d`, but the line in that file should have something like `GROUP="mygroup"` instead of `RUN="/path/to/script"`.

If you want to do something more complex, such as setting an access control list, you'll need to run a script. You don't need to escalate permissions in that script: it's already running as root! Just call the program you need to run as root, e.g. `setfacl`.

Answer (score 2):

I do not recommend this solution, for this problem.

You can edit `/etc/sudoers` to configure sudo to allow execution of a script without a password.

Comment: `includedir /dev/usb/` is this a correct entry to `/etc/sudoers`?

Comment: NOOOOOOOOO: That will read in the files in `dev/usb` and try to interpret them as rules for sudo. Also what I guess you are trying to do also looks like a bad idea: telling sudo to allow any operation on a directory, especially such a sensitive one, will not end well.

Comment: I think I should go for steeldriver's solution for this. Thanks