# Creating a script that runs on insertion of bootable medium (USB / External Harddrive / CD)

Tags: ubuntu, scripting, uefi, usb-drive

Say I have a script `script.sh`. How can I make it execute whenever a bootable medium is inserted? So lets say I stick a bootable cd into my PC, I want `script.sh` to run on insertion without rebooting my machine. Similar to:

[How to run custom scripts upon USB device plug-in?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28548/how-to-run-custom-scripts-upon-usb-device-plug-in)

but I don't want to distinguish between IDs and I want it to affect more than USBs... CDs and Harddrives as well.

Also,if possible, I would really like to pass information about the drive/cd to the script when it is inserted... My script is supposed to [create a efi boot entry](https://superuser.com/questions/1542667/refresh-efi-entries-that-show-under-efibootmgr/1543375#1543375) based on this inserted device, so I need to pass the devices information (port location, label, etc.) to `script.sh`.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is the same as in [How to run custom scripts upon USB device plug-in?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28548/how-to-run-custom-scripts-upon-usb-device-plug-in). You simply don't specify what you don't need to:

Original:

```
KERNEL=="sd*", ATTRS{vendor}=="Yoyodyne", ATTRS{model}=="XYZ42", ATTRS{serial}=="123465789", RUN+="/pathto/script"
```

Without caring about the vendor, model, serial:

```
KERNEL=="sd*", RUN+="/pathto/script"
```

You can pass parameters to the script, %k  for example is substituted by the device name.

Check the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/udev) for the full list and more information.

And I suggest using:

```
$ udevadm monitor
```

To debug the rules.

Comment: I didnt think it would be that easy! Thanks!