# Udev rule to connect USB to CAN Lawicell

Tags: shell-script, udev, canbus

I am using a Lawicel CAN adapter to connect to a sensor, and would like to setup a udev rule to avoid the manual can setup.

The manual can setup:

```bsh
sudo slcand -o -c -f -s6 /dev/ttyUSB0 slcan0
sudo ifconfig slcan0 up
```

Running `candump slcan0` shows, by printing data, that the connection works.

I am thus following a guide to setting up the udev rule from [link](http://pascal-walter.blogspot.com/2015/08/installing-lawicel-canusb-on-linux.html). But this doesn't work. The udev rule is

```bsh
# Lawicel CANUSB module
ACTION=="add", ENV{ID_MODEL}=="CANUSB", ENV{SUBSYSTEM}=="tty", RUN+="/usr/bin/logger [udev] Lawicel CANUSB detected - running slcan_add.sh!", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/slcan_add.sh $kernel"
ACTION=="remove", ENV{ID_MODEL}=="CANUSB", ENV{SUBSYSTEM}=="usb", RUN+="/usr/bin/logger [udev] Lawicel CANUSB removed - running slcan_remove.sh!", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/slcan_remove.sh"
```

and the `slcan_add.sh` script is

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
# Bind the USBCAN device
slcand -o -c -f -s6 /dev/$1 slcan0
sleep 2
ifconfig slcan0 up
```

then I reload the rules and restart udev, and `tail -f /var/log/syslog` returns the following

```bsh
morten@thinkpad:~$ tail -f /var/log/syslog
Oct  7 10:56:21 thinkpad kernel: [ 1580.917239] usb 1-1: Detected FT232RL
Oct  7 10:56:21 thinkpad kernel: [ 1580.918002] usb 1-1: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB0
Oct  7 10:56:21 thinkpad mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 10: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1"
Oct  7 10:56:21 thinkpad mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 10 was not an MTP device
Oct  7 10:56:21 thinkpad root: [udev] Lawicel CANUSB detected - running slcan_add.sh!
Oct  7 10:56:21 thinkpad slcand[5967]: starting on TTY device /dev/ttyUSB0
Oct  7 10:56:21 thinkpad slcand[5968]: attached TTY /dev/ttyUSB0 to netdevice slcan0
Oct  7 10:56:21 thinkpad slcand[5968]: netdevice slcan0 renamed to slcan0
Oct  7 10:56:21 thinkpad NetworkManager[649]: <info>  [1633596981.6497] manager: (slcan0): new Generic device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/8)
Oct  7 10:56:21 thinkpad systemd-udevd[5954]: ethtool: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
Oct  7 10:56:23 thinkpad snapd[668]: hotplug.go:199: hotplug device add event ignored, enable experimental.hotplug
Oct  7 10:56:23 thinkpad mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 10: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1"
Oct  7 10:56:23 thinkpad mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 10 was not an MTP device
Oct  7 10:56:26 thinkpad ModemManager[791]: <info>  [base-manager] couldn't check support for device '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1': not supported by any plugin
Oct  7 10:56:27 thinkpad gnome-shell[1997]: Removing a network device that was not added
Oct  7 10:56:27 thinkpad gnome-shell[1426]: Removing a network device that was not added
```

and `candump slcan0` returns `SIOCGIFINDEX: No such device`. How should I fix this?

**NOTE**: Using ubuntu 20.04.

**EDIT**: The udev rule properly recognizes the device and runs the script, so the udev rule should work I figure. If I manually set the usb port and run the shell script with `sudo ./sclan_add.sh` then it also works, displaying the following in `tail -f /var/log/syslog`

```bsh
Oct  7 12:53:26 agrirobot slcand[20933]: starting on TTY device /dev/ttyUSB0
Oct  7 12:53:26 agrirobot slcand[20934]: attached TTY /dev/ttyUSB0 to netdevice slcan0
Oct  7 12:53:26 agrirobot slcand[20934]: netdevice slcan0 renamed to slcan0
Oct  7 12:53:26 agrirobot NetworkManager[649]: <info>  [1633604006.8360] manager: (slcan0): new Generic device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/22)
Oct  7 12:53:26 agrirobot systemd-udevd[20936]: ethtool: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
```

I can't really see what the problem is with the udev rule calling the shell script, but for some reason this makes the difference.

Comment: I feel like this is hard to troubleshoot/verify given that the current setup doesn't work, the solving of which is my primary concern. That being said, I'm not 100% sure what the kernel parameter is doing in this context. I'm very new to udev rules.

Comment: In your ACTION=="add" udev rule, the 1st positional parameter $kernel appears to be undefined, unless it is a variable that you have previously exported. I suspect (from the tutorial you referenced) it could be slcan?... (wild-ish guess here !). You need to check the device name when you plug it and verify that it is not subject to changes from one plug action to the next... You can probably get the device name with `lsblk | grep dev`.

Comment: I suspect the `$kernel` is a misnomer. It is in fact the "device" name, which you can get per my modified comment.

Comment: device name, meaning `ttyUSB0` or what?

Comment: I don't think this is the problem, if you check the lines after `starting on TTY device /dev/ttyUSB0` you'll see it does actually start the device. Also when I tried to start it manually I confirmed that the dev port is correct.

The problem in setting up the can interface comes from elsewhere.

Comment: Note: deviations in the syslog response to the manual can setup and this automated version starts at the `snapd[668]:` line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was a combination of things, partially inspired by [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28548/how-to-run-custom-scripts-upon-usb-device-plug-in).

**udev rule**

```
# Lawicel CANUSB module
ACTION=="add", ENV{ID_MODEL}=="CANUSB", ENV{SUBSYSTEM}=="tty", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/slcan_add_wrapper.sh $kernel"
```

**slcan_add_wrapper.sh**

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
#  Call shell script binding can device
/usr/bin/logger "[udev] Lawicel CANUSB detected - running /usr/local/bin/slcan_add.sh on $1"
echo /usr/local/bin/slcan_add.sh $1 | at now
```

**slcan_add.sh**

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
# Bind the USBCAN device
sleep 1
/usr/bin/logger "binding $1 to slcan0"
slcand -o -c -f -s6 /dev/$1 slcan0
sleep 2
ifconfig slcan0 up
```

#### Description

The solution combines utilizing `at` to avoid udev killing the script for taking too long as well as a, slightly, magic `sleep` at the start of `slcan_add.sh`. Running `slcan_add.sh` from the terminal manually works without the sleep, but for some reason the udev rule refuses to without the sleep, I don't know why and I don't want to troubleshoot this anymore.

If someone finds a cleaner solution then I'll accept it.